# MonoTouch auto proxy network credentials not working

Tags: c#, proxy, xamarin.ios, webrequest

Trying to load some data off my server (xml data). I normally just use HttpWebRequest as I can set the utomaticDecompression to DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate in order to use gzip compression of my data automatically.

Recently a client has emailed me saying that it does not work from within his school. Sent out another copy of the app to him via TestFlightApp to get more debugging info from him and the app responds with a 407 auth error. Since then I have set up a proxy on my computer which I redirect my iPhone traffic through to test on.

My original setup was like so,

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
request.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
request.Proxy = null;
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

and then so on from there.

I'd set Proxy to null because in most cases the user would not be behind a proxy and this cut off 1-2 seconds of proxy resolving. There is code later to catch this and then re-create the HttpWebRequest but by not nulling the proxy, which I thought would be default proxy. Apparently not so...

I tried to then get the default proxy settings of the device.

```
CFProxySettings proxy0 = CFNetwork.GetSystemProxySettings();
IWebProxy proxy1 = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
IWebProxy proxy2 = HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
IWebProxy proxy3 = HttpWebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
IWebProxy proxy4 = CFNetwork.GetDefaultProxy();
```

proxy1 - proxy4 have null for the credentials. proxy0 contains proxy information which I need such as proxy url, port, username, but no password...

I manually made a WebProxy with my credentials

```
WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy(proxy0.HTTPProxy, proxy0.HTTPPort);
webProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
request.Proxy = webProxy;
```

and this works.
Falling short of requesting username and password for the proxy on a 407 error I am not sure what to do...
WebClient downloads do not work, but UIWebView and MKMapView does auto-auth itself.

Any ideas what I am missing?

EDIT:

Found this, https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1081

Comment: From what I have noticed: The Simulator uses the Mac OS proxy for its built in apps like Safari. However the proxy is not detected inside apps I write in MonoTouch. I have to set it up manually. On the device, the default proxy is the one that is configured in the device's network settings. So on the device you will be fine if you use DefaultWebProxy().

Comment: Do you mean "HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy" ? 

Just retested this on my device and proxy1 through to proxy4 are all null for credentials and return a 407 still.

Comment: Have you set up a proxy on your device's WLAN settings?

Comment: Yes. Safari will navigate through the proxy, as will a UIWebView.

Comment: Hmm, getting the credentials from iOS could be tricky, not sure.  I'll have a look at this next week, will post progress in that bug report.

Comment: In the meantime I am going to use this which I wrote.

https://github.com/ytn3rd/FourPiLibs/blob/master/FourPiLib/FourPiLib/Web/DataDownloader.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look at this today, doing a lot of debugging and browsing Apple's Documentation - and I'm afraid, I don't have a positive answer for you - unless you consider "impossible" as a positive answer ...

**The Problem in General**

According to [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFProxySupport/Reference/reference.html), `CFProxySupport` does not give you access to the stored proxy credentials.

There is an - undocumented - way of getting the proxy username (the returned dictionary uses strings as keys, one of these keys is called "HTTPUser" or "HTTPProxyUsername", but I couldn't find any string constant for it), but not the password.

**On Mac OS X**

There is actually a solution on Mac OS X: when I ran a simple `NSURLConnection` based example, it asked me for permission to access the keychain, so I opened the Keychain Utility and found the proxy credentials in the login keychain.  I also wrote a simple Objective C function to retrieve it, but you need to know the proxy user name (but I haven't tried using `NULL`, maybe that works).

I also couldn't find any way of checking whether authentication is required at all, except by checking whether that username is NULL.  Unfortunately, you need keychain access privileges to check whether some item exists, so we need to make sure that authentication is actually requierd.  One way of doing that would be from inside `HttpWebConnection` after it already received the HTTP 407 (and of these also contain the desired username).

**On iOS**

From what I've read so far on the internet, iOS does not let you access the system keychain - I'm not even sure whether that exists at all.  The `CFProxySupport` also doesn't return any credentials.

Fwiw., you also don't ever need to know the proxy password unless you want to do HTTP access without using the iOS APIs for it.  So there's a decent chance that there's just no way of retrieving it.

As a solution, you could either use the iOS APIs such as `NSURLConnection` or `WebClient` with the [CFNetwork](https://github.com/mono/maccore/tree/master/src/CFNetwork) handler.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Thats what I eventually did, https://github.com/ytn3rd/FourPiLibs/blob/master/FourPiLib/FourPiLib/Web/DataDownloader.cs, supports sync/async and writing directly to file or returning a string.